# Inconsistent error in RStudio in Web-scraping script: "arguments imply differing number of rows: 31, 30"

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rstudio, extract

(edited to make question and problem clearer)
I am running a script (R) to scrape Goodreads reviews. Recently, I get the following error message for some of the pages I'm trying to scrape:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 31, 30
```

The numbers at the end may change, f.e. `30, 33`.
What seems strange to me is that the error is not constant, it only occurs for some of the pages I'm trying to scrape, although the script itself remains the same. Example: scraping the reviews of *The Handmaid's Tale* (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38447.The_Handmaid_s_Tale?ac=1&from_search=true&qid=ZGrzc7AfLN&rank=1) causes an error (`32, 30`), but scraping the reviews of *Typhoon Kingdom* (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/52391186-typhoon-kingdom) causes no problems.

Full script:

```
library(rJava)        
library(data.table)   
library(dplyr)        
library(magrittr)     
library(rvest)        
library(RSelenium)    
library(lubridate)    
library(stringr)      
library(purrr)


options(stringsAsFactors = F) #needed to prevent errors when merging data frames

#Paste the Goodreads Url
url <- "https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6101138-wolf-hall"

englishOnly = F #If FALSE, all languages are chosen

#Set your browser settings
#Do NOT use Firefox! 
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "83.0.4103.39")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$setTimeout(type = "implicit", 2000)
remDr$navigate(url)

bookTitle = unlist(remDr$getTitle())
finalData = data.frame()

# Main loop going through the website pages
morePages = T
pageNumber =  1
while(morePages){

  #Select reviews in correct language
    selectLanguage = if(englishOnly){
    selectLanguage = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//select[@id='language_code']/option[@value='']")
  } else {
    selectLanguage = remDr$findElement("xpath", "//select[@id='language_code']/option[1]")
  }

  selectLanguage$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(3)

  #Expand all reviews
  expandMore <- remDr$findElements("link text", "...more")
  sapply(expandMore, function(x) x$clickElement())

  #Extracting the reviews from the page
  reviews <- remDr$findElements("css selector", "#bookReviews .stacked")
  reviews.html <- lapply(reviews, function(x){x$getElementAttribute("outerHTML")[[1]]})
  reviews.list <- lapply(reviews.html, function(x){read_html(x) %>% html_text()} )
  reviews.text <- unlist(reviews.list)

  #Get the review ID's from all the links
  reviewId = reviews.html %>% str_extract("/review/show/\\d+")
  reviewId = reviewId[!is.na(reviewId)] %>% str_extract("\\d+")

  #Some reviews have only rating and no text, so we process them separately
  onlyRating = unlist(map(1:length(reviews.text), function(i) str_detect(reviews.text[i], "^\\\n\\\n")))

  #Full reviews
  if(sum(!onlyRating) > 0){

    filterData = reviews.text[!onlyRating]
    fullReviews = purrr::map_df(seq(1, length(filterData), by=2), function(i){
      review = unlist(strsplit(filterData[i], "\n"))

      data.frame(
        date = mdy(review[2]), #date
        username = str_trim(review[5]), #user
        rating = str_trim(review[9]), #overall
        comment = str_trim(review[12]) #comment
      )
    })

    #Add review text to full reviews
    fullReviews$review = unlist(purrr::map(seq(2, length(filterData), by=2), function(i){
      str_trim(str_remove(filterData[i], "\\s*\\n\\s*\\(less\\)"))
    }))

  } else {
    fullReviews = data.frame()
  }

  #partial reviews (only rating)
  if(sum(onlyRating) > 0){

    filterData = reviews.text[onlyRating]
    partialReviews = purrr::map_df(1:length(filterData), function(i){
      review = unlist(strsplit(filterData[i], "\n"))

      data.frame(
        date = mdy(review[9]), #date
        username = str_trim(review[4]), #user
        rating = str_trim(review[8]), #overall
        comment = "",
        review = ""
      )
    })

  } else {
    partialReviews = data.frame()
  }

  finalData = rbind(finalData, cbind(reviewId, rbind(fullReviews, partialReviews)))

  #Go to next page if possible
  nextPage = remDr$findElements("xpath", "//a[@class='next_page']")
  if(length(nextPage) > 0){
    message(paste("PAGE", pageNumber, "Processed - Going to next"))
    nextPage[[1]]$clickElement()
    pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
    Sys.sleep(2)
  } else {
    message(paste("PAGE", pageNumber, "Processed - Last page"))
    morePages = FALSE
  }

}   
#end of the main loop

#Replace missing ratings by 'not rated'
finalData$rating = ifelse(finalData$rating == "", "not rated", finalData$rating)

#Stop server
rD[["server"]]$stop()

#Write results
write.csv(finalData, paste0(bookTitle, ".csv"), row.names = F)
message("FINISHED!")
```

I've removed some parts of the code to find out where the problem comes from and it seems to me that it must be caused by this piece of code that extracts the review-IDs:

```
#Get the review ID's from all the links
  reviewId = reviews.html %>% str_extract("/review/show/\\d+")
  reviewId = reviewId[!is.na(reviewId)] %>% str_extract("\\d+")
```

When I remove this piece of code and change `finalData = rbind(finalData, cbind(reviewId, rbind(fullReviews, partialReviews)))` to `finalData = rbind(finalData, fullReviews, partialReviews)`, the script runs without problems and without causing any errors. However, I really need to be able to extract these review-IDs to properly anonymise my data, so leaving it out is not an option.

I've tried to exchange that part of the code with this, as this should also be able to scrape the review-ID as well(but please correct me if I'm wrong):

```
#Get the review ID's from all the links
  reviewId = reviews.html %>% str_extract("review_\\d+")
  reviewId = reviewId[!is.na(reviewId)] %>% str_extract("\\d+")
```

This did not solve the problem and caused the same error, though with some differences: 1. the error has completely different numbers: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :   arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 30` and 2. the error now occurs for every single URL instead of for some, so I've actually managed to somehow make it worse.

As I don't have a lot of  experience working with R (or scripts in general), this is about as far as my knowledge and solution skills stretch.  I'm especially confused because the error only occurs for some URLs and not for the others. If you want to try it, you can simply run the full script as it is (it has a url for a book that caused an error). There is no need to change anything for a test run, except perhaps your chromever.

Does anyone know what causes this error and how it might be solved? Concrete steps would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: MartH if you want people to help you, maybe you should provide what you already try and a minimal repoducible example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RémiCoulaud Thank you for your comment! I've tried to locate the code that caused the issue and have described what I tried to do. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Thank you for all the material you add. It is a far better question. If you really want to improve the question. You could give a small part of script with only packages and line of code needed.

Comment: @RémiCoulaud You're welcome and thank you! This is my first time using this platform, so I wasn't sure how to go about it. The problem is that as I'm not very familiar with code and scripts I don't really understand what I can leave out and what not. To my inexperienced eyes all the part of a script seem essential somehow, but I'll try if I can find something!